# Intel Centrino wireless n-1000 problems

Tags: 11.10, wireless, intel-wireless

**[Translated Post]**
I am having problems in 11.10 with the Centrino n1000. If I am 5 meters away from the wireless router the signal lowers a lot. I have to be very close to it. I have googled for this. In windows it works correctly. Is it possible to solve this problem?

**[Original Post]**
sigo molestando por aca pues me he encontrado con otro problema creo si se puede resolver he visto mucho googlenado pero  en mi caso particular no ha funcionado, tengo una tarjeta intel centrino n1000 si funciona, solo que su intensidad es muy baja si estoy a mas de  5 metros del router, es inestable se desconecta mucho no se que tanto pueda mejorar la tarjeta, con windows obviamente funciona sin problema, una  pregunta si llegara a funcionar y estabilizarse ¿puede ser mas potente? he checado que muchos dispositivos de la computadora funcionan mucho mejor, muchas gracias, ciao.

pd descargue  compat-wireless intente seguir muchas instrucciones que lei pero no podia seguir con los pasos que algunos marcan en distintos posts.

Comment: Utilizar Ingles por favor ;)

Comment: i will do, thank you, i speak a little bit but i'll try

Comment: I only speak a little Spanish lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug files about this particular problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/836250

One of the comments mentions the Centrino n1000 but still it does not work correctly. I am guessing in the final 12.04 it might work properly. The user also points to have tested the RC2 of Ubuntu from the date he mentions so it might not be the same once 12.04 comes out.

Existe un bug mencionado sobre este problema particular. Alli puedes encontrar el comentario de otro usuario con la misma Centrino n1000 y el mismo problema. Posiblemente en la version final de la 12.04 te funcione mejor. Lo que podria recomendar seria probar el Beta y ver que tal te va. Te daria una idea de como va el progreso para esa tarjeta.